# Databindings is not a member of integer vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently creating a simple POS for a pharmacy so my codes are here

```vb
Dim currquan as Integer
```

```vb
cmd3.Connection = con3

cmd3.CommandText = "Select * from medicines where Drugs = " & Val(DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value.ToString) & ""
adapter1.SelectCommand = cmd3
ds1.Clear()
adapter1.Fill(ds1, "LIST")

currquan.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "List.Drugs")
currquan.DataBindings.Clear()

cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Now when I did the `currquan,databindings.add` it's highlighted and said "Databindings is not a member of integer"

I know to use parameters but I'm currently on a trial and error right now.

Comment: It looks like there's confusion between the `currquan` you declared as an `Integer` (which, as the error message says, does not have data bindings) and some other `currquan` that is a UI control.  You need to resolve this.  The best approach is probably to ensure that the UI control and the local variable have different names, as this will be less confusing for the reader/maintainer of the code.

Comment: A Select command is not a non query. For a Select command use `.ExecuteReader` or if you are expecting a single value `.ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: You have already executed your command when you called `.Fill` on the DataAdapter. Don't call .ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: Why would you add bindings and then clear them on the very next line?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question,
what you are trying to do is add a databinding to an integer. The integer type does not have that capability. Instead of using databinding, you can just set the "currquan" value once.

```
cmd3.Connection = con3
cmd3.CommandText = "Select * from medicines where Drugs = " & Val(DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value.ToString) & ""
adapter1.SelectCommand = cmd3
ds1.Clear()
adapter1.Fill(ds1, "LIST")

currquan = ds.List.Drugs.Count
'currquan.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "List.Drugs")
'currquan.DataBindings.Clear()

cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

if you need to refresh this number just run this code again to update the list.

Any questions just ask.